# Using mysql triggers on 2 unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create a user activity log which I then insert into the database. And for this, I'm thinking of using mysql triggers instead of placing a query that would do this on every successful query.
The 2 tables have no relationship at all.
Here's an example:

**table_fruits**

- fruit name
- flavor

**table_log**

- user id
- name of table
- time stamp

**table_users**

- user id

Now every time I insert on table fruits, the trigger that would insert the values into table_log would also executes. My problem here is getting the user id which is stored in another table. How do I determine which user id to insert. As far as I know triggers doesn't require parameters, so I can't probably use that to supply the id from my script.
Any ideas? Should I just use stored procedures for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 approaches to this:

- As you mentioned, use a stored proc to insert into both main table and a log table
- **Store the user ID (supplied by the app) as a column in main (fruit) table as "inserted_by" column; then have the trigger populate the log table and read the user from the main table**.
- Have the trigger automatically figure out the userid. This has two flavors:

  1. User IDs exist on applications side, but NOT on database side (e.g. a user logs in to a web page, but the CGI backend code always connects to a database as special "http" database user).
  2. User ID from the app actually connects to DB as identically named database user.

     In this case, you should use **[`USER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user)** (but **NOT** `current_user()` which instead returns whoever created the trigger, or more precisely, which ID was used for trigger permission check)

Answer (score 1):

When you insert into the fruits table, you also know the user_id value.

I would suggest create an blackhole table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE bh_fruit (
  user_id integer not null,
  fruit_name varchar(255), 
  flavor varchar(255)
) ENGINE = BLACKHOLE;
```

Put a trigger on the blackhole table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_bh_fruit_each AFTER INSERT ON bh_fruit FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fruit (fruit_name, flavor) VALUES (NEW.fruit_name, NEW.flavor);
  INSERT INTO log (user_id, tablename) VALUES (NEW.user_id, 'fruit');
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now your php code becomes:

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
$fruit = mysql_real_escape_string($fruit);
$flavor = mysql_real_escape_string($flavor);
$sql = "INSERT INTO bh_fruit (user_id, fruit_name, flavor) 
          VALUES ('$user_id','$fruit','$flavor')";
```